# merging contents run time error in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml

I have problem with the XML file in android studio I'm very new to it and I want to design a text and below the text, there are two buttons but when it runs all content located at (0,0) location at the end only the last button appear in the device 
here's my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.tabarek.mysecondapplication.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Information!"
    android:id="@+id/hello"
     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="SayHi"
    android:text="About Me"
    android:layout_below="@+id/hello"
     />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="SayHi"
    android:text="My Email"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

at the end,
the result appears like this
 [image]

can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

try this use `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hello"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Information!" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="SayHi"
        android:text="About Me" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="SayHi"
        android:text="My Email" />
</LinearLayout>
```